# Find a particular solution to the system $\dot{x}=Ax+e^{-t}\begin{bmatrix} -2 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been given the following matrix:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & -2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
I have been told to find a particular solution to the following system:
$$\dot{x}=Ax+e^{-t}\begin{bmatrix}
-2 \\
0 \\
1\end{bmatrix}$$
I don't know how to do it. Can someone help me with this? It is just practise for my next semester

Comment: What book are you reading?

Comment: You can take the Laplace transform of the differential equation.  Solve for X(s).  Find the inverse Laplace transform.

Comment: I am reading "Differential equations and infinite series" by Ole Christensen

Comment: A particular solution is of the form $e^{-t}\begin{bmatrix}
a \\
b\\
c\end{bmatrix}.$ Now determine $a,b,c.$

Comment: But how? Can you give me a hand with it?

Comment: @DiscoCarl Fred said that put $x(t) = e^{-t}[a;b;c]$ and find $[a;b;c]$. We can do that because know that $e^{-t} \neq 0$ for all $t \ge 0$.

Comment: @Hermis14 I still understand how you can solve it like this. What are you meant to do? I don't get your explanation